# Robohelp: How to reference a .chm file rather than copy it into a merged project?

Tags: html, chm, robohelp

I am assigning new .CHM files to existing merged projects. You may recognize this dialog:

[image]

When I go to assign a (in my case) an existing merged project a new .CHM file, I am presented with this dialog. However, I do not want the .CHM file to be copied in, I want it to reference a .CHM file. This is because I am working on a help project that compiles many other help projects that get changed separately from time to time. This leaves the compilation project out of date if the .CHM files are simply copied in; they're just older copies.

Is there a way to have a merged project point to a .CHM file rather than copy it in so that it reflects outside changes made to the .CHM file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone was very helpful on Adobe forums and posted a video about my question. The short answer is that, as far as I can tell, RH cannot "reference" a file. If you want child projects .CHM files to appear in a master project, you must either copy the files manually, or output from the child project build separately to each directory you would like to have an updated .CHM in.

Here's the vid:
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q774WbvYd-c&feature=youtu.be][1]